# Solving extended positive definite system with Cholesky factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have a system of equations:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{A} & \boldsymbol{1} \\
\boldsymbol{1}^\top & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{x} \\
x_0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{b} \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $\boldsymbol{A} \succ 0$ is symmetric positive definitive. How would you exploit the Cholesky factorization of $\boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{L}\boldsymbol{L}^\top$ to efficiently solve this system for various right-hand-side $\boldsymbol{b}$?

If there is no efficient trick with the Cholesky factorization, what would you recommend to guarantee decent numerical stability and speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have 
$$
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+x_0\mathbf{1}=\mathbf{b}, \quad
\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x}=1.
$$
Eliminate $\mathbf{x}$ from the first equation and substitute to the second:
$$
\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{A}^{-1}(\mathbf{b}-x_0\mathbf{1})
\quad\implies\quad
\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}(\mathbf{b}-x_0\mathbf{1})=1.
$$
This gives
$$
x_0=\frac{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}-1}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{1}}.
$$

So you can first solve using Cholesky the systems
$$
\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{b}, \quad \mathbf{f}=\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{1},
$$
and then form $x_0$ and $\mathbf{x}$ as
$$
x_0=\frac{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{y}-1}{\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{f}}, \quad
\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}-x_0\mathbf{f}.
$$